# Filtering the NS array and getting the element according to the issynced value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nslog

I'm working in objective c. Here i need the array element which contains IsSynced = 0 in my NSlog. I need to filter the resultArry.

```
{
        ActivityTime = "2018-07-24T05:48:25.017Z";
        EntityId = "B88476DA-3707-4B37-A1E0-142875CFAE6E";
        ErrorCode = "<null>";
        ErrorData = "<null>";
        ErrorMessage = "<null>";
        IsSynced = 0;
        Message = "Waybill 'QBZZ222220180724111804' created.";
        PropertyId = "8c0ad0da-4505-40d5-8201-a7818a3d055a";
        PropertyPIC = QBZZ2222;
        RecentActivityId = "79A6E4D7-2D60-4635-9A70-C4E55D5A1399";
        TableNames = NVD;
    },
        {
        ActivityTime = "2018-07-23T11:31:25.905Z";
        EntityId = "23AE3D5E-8423-428F-9678-7BB3A75EF320";
        ErrorCode = "<null>";
        ErrorData = "<null>";
        ErrorMessage = "<null>";
        IsSynced = 1;
        Message = "Waybill 'QBZZ222220180723170035' created.";
        PropertyId = "8c0ad0da-4505-40d5-8201-a7818a3d055a";
        PropertyPIC = QBZZ2222;
        RecentActivityId = "2C3C7047-F43C-4521-8B66-419AF31EC766";
        TableNames = NVD;
    },


        {
        ActivityTime = "2018-07-23T09:44:32.483Z";
        EntityId = "49914A90-8F05-4479-B2C8-49C34637E70B";
        ErrorCode = "<null>";
        ErrorData = "<null>";
        ErrorMessage = "<null>";
        IsSynced = 1;
        Message = "Waybill 'QBZZ222220180723151237' created.";
        PropertyId = "8c0ad0da-4505-40d5-8201-a7818a3d055a";
        PropertyPIC = QBZZ2222;
        RecentActivityId = "DCCF5B03-7AD3-404F-A235-006DF3A37F97";
        TableNames = NVD;
    },
```

This is my code

```
SArray *resultArry =  [[DBHelper getSharedInstance] getRecordsBySQL:propertyQuery];

    //NSString *recentactivitylog=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultArry encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity:%@" ,resultArry);
    NSPredicate *notsynced = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"resultArry.IsSynced = 1"];
    NSArray *notsyncedenvds = [resultArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:notsynced];
    NSLog(@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity which is not synced:%@" ,notsyncedenvds);
```

I just need the array element which has the value IsSynced as 0  in my NSlog as you can see this element below.

```
{
        ActivityTime = "2018-07-24T05:48:25.017Z";
        EntityId = "B88476DA-3707-4B37-A1E0-142875CFAE6E";
        ErrorCode = "<null>";
        ErrorData = "<null>";
        ErrorMessage = "<null>";
        IsSynced = 0;
        Message = "Waybill 'QBZZ222220180724111804' created.";
        PropertyId = "8c0ad0da-4505-40d5-8201-a7818a3d055a";
        PropertyPIC = QBZZ2222;
        RecentActivityId = "79A6E4D7-2D60-4635-9A70-C4E55D5A1399";
        TableNames = NVD;
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code I'm not getting any element after filtering the predicate. Sorry I'm new to Objective-c.

Comment: your NSLog has correct value IsSynced = 0; then what's the problem ?

Comment: @Vinodh I'm not getting the array elements which has the value  IsSynced = 0; it just gives elements for NSArray *notsyncedenvds  as o elements instead it should get the 1 element which has the value IsSynced = 0;  from the list of array elements and display it in Nslog

Comment: I just mentioned the second array element as an example which I should get in my NSlog.Please see my code @Vinodh

Comment: then you should change predicate with format IsSynced == 0 and not IsSynced == 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     NSPredicate *notsynced = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"IsSynced == 0 || IsSynced == %@",@"0"];
     NSArray *notsyncedenvds = [resultArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:notsynced];
     NSLog(@"This is the eNVDS in Recent Activity which is not synced:%@" ,notsyncedenvds);
```

or

for fast enumeration with large amount of data

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableAraay alloc]init];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in resultArry){
        NSString *IsSynced = [NSStrinf StringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectforkey:@"IsSynced"]];
        if([IsSynced integerValue] = 0){
        [arr addObject:dict];
        }
     }
     NSLog(@"IsSynced zero value array %@",arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The predicate is wrong. You must not include the array itself

```
NSPredicate *notsynced = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"IsSynced = 1"];
```

But as you need the item(s) with `IsSynced = 0` then you have to filter fo that:

```
NSPredicate *notsynced = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"IsSynced = 0"];
```

In case the value for key `IsSynced` is a string you have to add single quotes

```
NSPredicate *notsynced = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"IsSynced = '0'"];
```